# Normalize group-wise in a ggplot bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the same problem as was described in this question: [normalized bar heights in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969436/normalized-bar-heights-in-ggplot/66974289#66974289) (I post this as a new question because my reputation is too low to comment.) I want the blue bars to integrate to 1 and the red ones as well, and I think this is what the accepted answer provides. But it does not work for me, because I get this error:

```
Aesthetics must be valid computed stats. Problematic aesthetic(s): y = ..density... 
Did you map your stat in the wrong layer?
```

when I do exactly as vpipkt suggested:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = bin, y = ..density.., group = source, fill = source)) +
geom_bar(alpha = 0.5, position = 'identity')
```

using the example data provided by user3396385:

```
set.seed(47)
BG.restricted.hs = round(runif(100, min = 47, max = 1660380))
FG.hs = round(runif(1000, min = 0, max = 1820786))

dat = data.frame(x = c(BG.restricted.hs, FG.hs), 
            source = c(rep("BG", length(BG.restricted.hs)),
            rep("FG", length(FG.hs))))
dat$bin = cut(dat$x, breaks = 200)
```

With `..count..` instead of `..density..` however, there is no error:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = bin, y = ..count.., group = source, fill = source)) +
geom_bar(alpha = 0.5, position = 'identity')
```

But it has the same problem as the examples in the original questions, the data set with less weight count overall is less visible. Since the answer was accepted I assume that it must have worked at some point.. any ideas what might have gone wrong since then? I would be very happy if someone could tell me if they are having the same issues. Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states that `..density..` is not available and thus cannot be mapped to the `y` aesthetic. I think this is because `..density..` is not computed by `geom_bar()` (anymore).

Use `..prop..` instead:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x = bin, group = source, fill = source)) +
  geom_bar(alpha = 0.5, position = 'identity', aes(y = ..prop..))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you could also post this answer to the original question? Then mine could be marked as a duplicate or deleted..